# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) issue for Kendo dll files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

When I run my Asp.Net MVC web page it shows the following error in browser console.Here I use BundleConfig for load Js files.

http://localhost:59574/Verification/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please paste here the BundleConfig code  you are using . look like you are pointing to wrong cdn or the files does not existing on your local machine.

Comment: Post your BundleConfig.cs and the layout or view page content. Check if your `Styles.Render` method works with minified CSS file.